# compiz problems with launcher

Tags: 14.04, compiz

I downloaded compiz and enabled window decorating and after doing so my launcher or side bar did not show up any more and can't get it back what should I do?

I also can't access the terminal and the top bar.

Comment: Can you access a tty session by pressing CTRL+ALT+F1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Window decorations are now handled in Unity, by enabling the window deco plugin you have disabled the unity plugin.

Navigate in nautilus to /usr/share/applications, click on the `CompizConfig Settings Manager` icon. Once open re-enable `Ubuntu Unity Plugin` ( click on plugin entry to find the option to enable

If you don't have any folders on the Desktop to open nautilus then just r. click > New Folder to create one.